Thunderbird 350x acceleration problem
Recently I got some problem with my thunderbird bike. When I try to start my bike it is not working but when I try to put choke mode , it's starting well and when I start accelerating the bike , i noticed that there is some lag in acceleration and when I make idle, I can see the acceleration delay in it. (I.e) Acceleration is still revving for 1 to 2 seconds. May i know what could be the problem.
To resolve this I just replaced my engine oil and charged the battery but still issue is there
Thanks in advance,

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! During the time you are trying to accelerate it, is the choke on?

When starting the bike i keep it in choke but when I accelerate it is in normal mode I will just turn off the choke.

As a guess, I'd suggest this is a fueling problem with your accelerator pump in the carb. When you twist the throttle there is a large influx of air which the regular carb venturis cannot keep up with. This creates a lean condition and can affect acceleration. It is at least a place to start. If not this, I'd still suggest there is a problem with the carb.

Will it get resolved if I clean the carburettor and change the spark plug?

Probably not with that alone. You need to diagnose this is the issue, otherwise you're chasing your tail. If the accelerator pump is the problem, more than likely you'd need to have the carb rebuilt.
